# How do you fix this error: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using unity code to make a game, and I get this error:

> "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or
> methods."

This is my code:

```
public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PlayGame ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}   

public void GQ ()
{
    Debug.Log ("QUIT!");
    Application.Quit();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is `GQ` a part of the class or not? Count the braces.

Comment: `public void GQ ()` has to be defined inside the class, not outside.

Comment: This is not Unity specific but the nature of C#, you cannot have a method without it existing within a Class.  You can create static classes and static methods inside those classes. The Unity Application class is a static as is the Quit method inside it, hence calling it with `Application.Quit();`.  I recommend that you place the method inside your MainMenu class or learn about Statics and implement a solution that works for your requirement. [Mircosoft Static Classes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

Answer (score 1):

Put your `GQ()` method code inside the class.

```
public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void PlayGame ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }

    public void GQ ()
    {
        Debug.Log ("QUIT!");
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Your Unity `C#` script can contain *only* `1` public class. Every attributes and methods have to be defined *only* inside the class. Nothing except the imports should be written outside the class